# SQL Server date format MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I check if a date string is in the MM/DD/YYYY format in SQL Server?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;
SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE(@string) = 1 
  AND @string LIKE '[0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]' 
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

If the result is 1, it's a valid date, but there's no guarantee that it's the date the user meant. If they enter:

```
06/07/2012
```

There is no way to know if they meant June 7 or July 6. Your best bet is to make users pick dates from drop-downs or calendar controls, which allows you to control the format and avoid any needless interpretation. Your application layer can use strongly typed variables / parameters and insert into properly typed columns.

Comment: +1 - It should be noted that this is of course hinting that dates/times should **ABSOLUTELY NOT** be stored as string types, but as their proper types.  If you're trying to figure out what a database is using... you could be in for some trouble.

Answer (score 4):

If you're after the SQL Server dateformat to see whether it's MDY then use:

```
dbcc useroptions
```

And have a look at the *dateformat* Set Option

Answer (score 3):

you convert date to datestring in this format  MM/DD/YYYY using [CONVERT function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
select convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101)
```

The output will be as of Sept 8th 2012

```
09/08/2012
```

There is no need to validate, other then checking the date field is null or not

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it outside the database. A database stores datetime internally in its own format. I dont think you can read what format the date is stored in. You can read it which ever way you like, for example dd/mm/yyyy or yyyy/mm/dd etc.

What you can do is check this value outside the database for any date field. You can use regular expression for that. But that will be outside the database.