# How to check if a given date is in yyyymmdd format sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I spent quit a long time and could not figure out how can i check if a given date is in YYYYMMDD format. Can anyone suggest me a simple way that this can be achieved in sql

Thanks.

Comment: You do know a date is never "in this format" because dates have no intrinsic format - the format is a visualization always. The "internal format" of a date is a number.

Comment: check this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266518/sql-server-date-format-mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: +1 for asking a beginner question and getting absolutely rude responses.

Answer (score 4):

Once you updated to SQL Server 2012 you can use `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST` to test strings.

By using `TRY_CONVERT(DATE, MyColumn, 112)`  you will ether get values or nulls when conversion failed because string was `YYYYDDMM` format.

For SQL Server before 2012 best thing you can do is wrap `CONVERT(DATE, MyColumn, 112)` inside of `TRY CATCH`. This will catch errors every time you try to convert the string that is not in correct format but this will not give you `NULL` results like `TRY_CONVERT` in 2012 will.

Answer (score 3):

You can, at best, ask if a **string** is representing a date in YYYYMMDD format. And the answer is **no**, there is no such way. You will never be able to distinguish between 20140305  (that is March 5th 2014) and 20140305 (aka May 3rd 2014). At best you can claim that you can answer with confidence *for certain dates*.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the try_cast to date with an isnumeric() check

```sql
select 1 where isnumeric('20210702') = 1 and try_cast('20210702' as date) is not null
```