# Date format checking

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is there any built in function in SQL Server 2008 where I can check date format of specific type and return true otherwise false.

For example, if I specify "yyyymmdd" as date format then all those records should be returned and if any other format date or characters are present then return false.

Please note that column data type is varchar(50) and different type of date format and invalid date data is present like

```
"20200831"  -- only correct format in my current situation

"1/8/20"

"Oct/1/2019"

"6 Months"

"01.12.2019"

"2019.11.05"

"12/Nov/2019"
```

Comment: Here is the details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266518/sql-server-date-format-mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: I can't use try_convert as it only works sql server 2012 and above and ISDate() as it will work with other date format.

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing built in, especially not in 2008 version (which is out of extended support for over a year now - time to seriously consider an upgrade).
The only thing you can do is use `like` (or `patindex`) with a numeric pattern:

```
SELECT <ColumnsList>
FROM <TableName>
WHERE <WhatShouldHaveBeenADateColumn> LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

and even then, you might encounter problems with values like `20200229` or `20000431`.

> Please note that column data type is varchar(50)

Well, that's a lesson you wont forget - [use the correct data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)
Store dates as dates and datetime as datetime2 and you'll never have to worry about format again, since [datetime doesn't have a format.](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in function, but there is a fairly simple way to validate a date. If you have a calendar table, then you could use something like this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.YourTable AS t
        INNER JOIN dbo.Calendar AS c
            ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), c.Date, 112) = t.VarcharDateColumn;
```

If you don't have a calendar table, then you should create one, they are very useful. If you can't create one, then you can create one on the fly for your query, e.g.

```
WITH N1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N3),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2)
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, '19000101'), 112)
FROM    N3;
```

You can read more about this technique, and others here: [Generate a set or series without loops](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)

You can then add this list of dates into your query:

```
WITH N1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N3),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
Dates AS (SELECT DateString = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, '19000101'), 112) FROM N3)

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.YourTable AS t
        INNER JOIN Dates AS d
            ON d.DateString = t.VarcharDateColumn;
```

All of this is far from ideal though. The ideal fix is to stop storing dates in a varchar column.

**FULL DEMO**

```
WITH N1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N3),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
Dates (Date) AS (SELECT TOP (100000) DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, '19000101') FROM N3)

SELECT  t.VarcharDate,
        d.Date
FROM    (VALUES 
            ('20200831'), ('20200432'), ('1/8/20'), ('Oct/1/2019'), 
            ('6 Months'), ('01.12.2019'), ('2019.11.05'), ('12/Nov/2019')
        ) T (VarcharDate)
        LEFT JOIN Dates AS d
            ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), d.Date, 112) = t.VarcharDate;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
VarcharDate     Date
-----------------------------
20200831        2020-08-31
2019.11.05      NULL
1/8/20          NULL
6 Months        NULL
20200432        NULL
Oct/1/2019      NULL
01.12.2019      NULL
12/Nov/2019     NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The function [`ISDATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) comes close.  However, it would allow other dates formats beyond the first.  I would suggest `ISDATE()` along with logic that says that you have no non-digits:

```
select (case when isdate(col) = 1 and
                  col not like '%[^0-9]%'
             then 1 else 0
        end) as is_date_flag
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b592e8a91402d37e63d43b1876a67071) is a db<>fiddle.

Supported versions of SQL Server (currently anything *after* SQL Server 2008) also have the `try_()` functions, which would be the right solution in more recent versions.